# Cookie settings dark on white theme and white on dark theme?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Is the following the correct behaviour or an error?

Stack Overflow is dark themed, but the cookie settings is white
[image: White on Dark]

on Meta StackOverflow it is white theme and dark cookie settings
[image: Dark on White]

Comment: If the floating dialog was always dark, it would have no contrast at all against the background in dark mode. Would be pretty sucky to use.

Comment: @yivi - had the same thought, that this may be the reasoning, but thought a border or dropshadow would have been enough to "confine" it from the underlying same color background, but in the end I simply wasn't sure if it is as desired or not

Comment: Even if it had a border to show contrast, it would look really bad.

Answer (score -3):

Actually, By my experience the inverse color for alert dialog boxes have better UX.

It is exactly correct.

Comment: `It is exactly correct.` are you assuming or stating a fact?

Comment: @RandRandom, It is a fact, see, I'm Frontend developer and I saw many designs, for better UX some critical alert dialog boxes should be very shiny. in fact, your question is very nice, because of this I upvoted it.

Comment: @AmerllicA It's really just an opinion, not a fact :-)

Answer (score -3):

Actually its is bugging me to..

I see why its done this way, but there so much other ways to make it dark on dark mode without having the same color as background.
There are enough colors to pick. Make it an other shade of gray or a dark shade of orange or blue or **violet**

Its a flaw in my opinion

Here some examples:

[image: Dark-Mode - Violet Cockie][image: Light-Mode - Violet Cockie]

[image: Dark-Mode - Orange Cockie][image: Light-Mode - Orange Cockie]

[image: Dark-Mode - Blue Cockie][image: Light-Mode - Blue Cockie]

Comment: Could you show an example? I cannot see the cookie dialog being violet or blue, because that just isn't enough contrast IMO.

Comment: Just to bring some objective numbers here, all of the dark-mode examples you've provided have really poor contrast ratios: [#1: 1:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=190131&bcolor=0D0D0D), [#3: 1.24:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=3C1B01&bcolor=0D0D0D), [#5: 1.11:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=000D38&bcolor=000000). Any alternative color suggestions really need to contrast from the dark background better than these do.

Comment: (By comparison, the ratios of the current colors are [12.2:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=3C1B01&bcolor=0D0D0D) in light mode and [10.16:1](https://webaim.org/resources/contrastchecker/?fcolor=DADEE0&bcolor=2D2D2D) in dark)